# Can we [push] this tag out of the way?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I propose that [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) be burninated for the following reasons:

1. A quick perusal of the questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) shows that it is very often not used consistent with its definition. It's meant to tag questions about pushing to remote VCS repositories but is often used to refer to the common Array operation, push notifications, or other concepts.
2. Even when it is used correctly, it provides no value. A question related to pushing in Git should be tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) or even [git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push). A question related to SVN is more appropriately tagged [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn), and so on.

As discussed below in comments, I would suggest that if [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) is burninated that [pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pull) also be removed, since the same arguments apply to both.

Comment: Aaah tssst [push] it (into the burninator)

Comment: So [git] has [git-pull] and [git-push]. There aren't SVN equivalents(yet). And what to do with [pull]? This isn't as simple as one tag...

Comment: For the lazy, it currently has 3,731 questions in it, a fairly substantial amount.

Comment: @Machavity I would burninate [pull] if [push] is approved, since the same arguments apply. I don't think that [git-pull] and [git-push] need to be part of this discussion.

Comment: There are also 489 questions tagged with [push] and [notifications] which should really be tagged [push-notification]. [Search Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push%20notifications)

Comment: IMHO [push] should be kept but it should be about pushing things into containers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's somewhat of a breakdown of the most popular combinations:

```
push + git: 1292                       push + google-cloud-messaging: 122
push + android: 603                    push + jquery: 139
push + notifications: 594              push + mercurial: 106
push + ios: 527                        push + stack: 84
push + arrays: 734                     push + flutter: 23
push + javascript: 720                 push + commit: 155
push + push-notification: 371          push + pull: 148
push + github: 483                     push + objective-c: 88
push + php: 204                        push + heroku: 104
push + iphone: 175                     push + cordova: 74
push + apple-push-notifications: 189   push + xcode: 81
push + firebase: 93                    push + repository: 65
push + java: 166                       push + docker: 38
push + react: 57                       push + node.js: 100
```

I'm fairly certain that the following points are accurate:

- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and any of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications), [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [apple-push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications), [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging), can be retagged to [push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification).
- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and [push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification) can simply have the [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) tag removed.
- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and any of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), or [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), can be retagged with [array-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-push)
- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and either [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) or [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) can be retagged with [git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push)
- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) can be retagged with [docker-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-push) or just use [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker)
- Questions tagged with [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) can be retagged to [push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification) *after the array questions have been retagged*

That leaves a lot of questions still left over, but takes care of a lot of the disambiguation. I don't know about a bunch of the other language tags used here, so if someone who is familiar with those languages would like to chime in with a possible alternative for questions using those tags, it would be appreciated.

I propose we perform the retags listed above, then see where we are at.

Comment: Is there any way to do bulk re-tags? I think this is a good solution but it's not practical to retag this many questions manually.

Comment: Community managers can perform bulk retagging. As it seems like all of this is fairly straightforward, I can imagine this being a good case for that. You would have to get a community manager's attention somehow, either by pinging them in chat, or flagging your post for moderator attention asking that a community manager look into it.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think we should burninate these tags. [pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pull) and [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) describe specific actions that you take in version control and tags exist to make questions easier to find. VCS is a pretty big topic without support tags. Remember, there's at least 4 VCS systems with questions that use this tag

- [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)
- [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn)
- [mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial)
- [cvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cvs)

Trying to hyphenate them all will result in chaos. [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) is the most popular and I would argue that [git-pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-pull) and [git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push) should be made synonyms of their ambiguous cousins(someone else can fight that fight). So if you have a question about a problem with pulling in git, it should be tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push), Mercurial should be [mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial) [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push), etc. And the tag should make it obvious [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) is strictly about VCS, and not things like [push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification)

The [four rules of burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) say to keep it

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   We should limit the scope of the tag to just VCS and retag anything else. The tag doesn't do a good job of limit itself, but an edit can fix that.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Yes
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Yes. These are actions related to VCS
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. This is the one failure of this tag. Being generic, people apply it anywhere they see fit. But if they ignore the stated purpose of the tag that's why we edit (and anyone can edit)

Comment: Just `push` is too broad, it can mean anything. As [@TinyGiant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344035/4927984) explained in his answer, there are more precise tags for each case.